# chcon fails to fix "cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires" err under RHEL6

Tags: rhel, selinux

I have an application I test at work, that has always failed installation on systems with SELinux enabled.  Our published workaround involves issuing a chcon command for the library-file at the center of the failure.

```
chcon -t textrel_shlib_t /usr/lib/ourfile.so.1.0.20
```

In RHEL5, this has worked for us, and allows the application to function correctly, without having to completely disable SELinux.

Under RHEL6, the chcon command gives no errors, but we still see the same error, when our application is started as a daemon, via `/etc/init.d/ourapp`

My primary concern is figuring out an updated workaround (the application library in question is submitted to an external certification process, and can't be changed for another 6 months), but I'm also curious if this indicates an intentional change from RHEL5 to RHEL6.

Answer (score 1):

The Unofficial SELinux FAQ contributes [this workaround](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/faq.html#CP.19).

This is caused by an extension to Linux called [Exec-Shield](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/nonselsec.pdf). It prevents programs from executing code on the stack, mitigating [stack smashing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection).

Most shared libraries do not need an executable stack, therefore you should mark the library as not needing an executable stack via:

```
execstack -c /usr/lib/ourfile.so.1.0.20
```

After using [execstack](http://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack), test the program to ensure that it still runs. If you have some bad code in there that actually tries to execute code on the stack, it will crash.

Comment: As I mentioned, the library isn't fixable for several months, and it does require execution of the stack, so this 'fix' doesn't help my current situation, nor explains why chcon worked under RHEL5, but doesn't under RHEL6.

Comment: You're stuck with fixing the library and waiting six months, then. I have no idea why your `chcon` was all you needed to make it work on EL5; it should not have worked as Exec-Shield is enabled by default on EL5 as well.